# Get all of the upvotes a user has received on all their questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my app, users can vote on questions and post questions.  I want to see how many total upvotes the user has *received* on their questions.

I wanted to do `user.questions.upvotes` but this doesn't seem to work because it's calling a method on an association. If I do `user.upvotes`, it will get all the upvotes a user has *given*, not *received*.

Let's use Stackoverflow as an example:

```
"user" has_many "questions"
"user" has_many "upvotes"

"question" belongs_to" "user"
"question" has_many "upvotes"

"upvote" belongs_to "user"
"upvote" belongs_to "question"
```

How do you get all the upvotes a user has received?

(Btw, if you know a more abstract title for this question, please comment so it is more easily searchable in the future. I couldn't think of one that was clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, after writing the whole thing realized it's just

Get all votes a person has received:
`user.questions.count(:votes)`

Get all votes a person has given:
`user.votes.count`

Comment: Ah, an excellent case of Rubber Duck Debugging. :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging